# Android TextInputLayout remains red after clearing error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I have a form with multiple `EditText` items each wrapped in a `TextInputLayout`. When clicking the Submit button, I check to see if the `EditText` is empty. If it is, I call an error on that field, e.g. `ageWrapper.setError("Age required")`. This shows an error message under the field, and also changes the `hint` of the `EditText` to red. This occurs for all input fields on the page and the errors are working fine.

The problem occurs after I clear the error. I first leave the field blank and submit - error shows up and things are displayed red. I then type something into the field, and submit again. Now, the error goes away as it should (`ageWrapper.setErrorEnabled(false)`), but the `hint` remains in red rather than changing back to its normal, non-error, colour.

This should not be happening because the error has been cleared by typing something into the field, and yet the hint is still red implying an error, even though the error message itself (under the field) disappears.

When I click the field again, or any other field on the page, the red hint text then changes back to its normal colour.

Clearly the error display is working - it displays and goes away as it should. But why does the hint text remain red after Ive cleared the error by typing something into the field, and only changes back to its regular colour after a click to the field itself (or another field)? How do I get rid of this behaviour?

In my mind, if both fields are empty, both will display red and show error messages. If I then fill in one of the fields, `setErrorEnabled(false)` should be set on that field and the hint text should go back to normal but it doesnt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/new_layout_padding">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_condition_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/input_subnum_wrapper">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_condition"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/new_form_element_height"
            android:hint="@string/input_text_condition"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_age_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/input_condition_wrapper">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_age"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/new_form_element_height"
            android:hint="@string/input_text_age"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/input_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="5"
        android:text="@string/input_button_save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java class for the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container, false);

    //Get all text fields
    conditionWrapper = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.input_condition_wrapper);
    ageWrapper = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.input_age_wrapper);

    //Listener for create button
    createButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.input_submit);
    createButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

//Create/submit button click
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Get input values
    String condition = conditionWrapper.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String age = ageWrapper.getEditText().getText().toString();

    //If all the validation passes, submit the form. Else, show errors
    if (!isEmpty(condition) & !isEmpty(age)) {
        //Submit form data
    } else {
        if (isEmpty(condition)) {
            conditionWrapper.setError("Condition required");
        } else {
            conditionWrapper.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        if (isEmpty(age)) {
            ageWrapper.setError("Age required");
        } else {
            ageWrapper.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}

//Check if a string is empty
public boolean isEmpty(String string) {
    if (string.equals("")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: use conditionWrapper.setError(null);

Comment: instead of `setErrorEnabled(false)`? Or in addition to?

Comment: instead of setErrorEnabled(false) place this code

Comment: perfect, thanks! If you post as an answer I'd be happy to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to

```
 if (isEmpty(condition)) {
            conditionWrapper.setError("Condition required");
        } else {
             conditionWrapper.setError(null);
        }
```

Comment: Noting my mistake for future reference. In case you're using `OutlinedBox` style and have tried to hide the strokeColor by setting `boxStrokeColor="@null"` in your xml, just clearing out the error as above won't help you get rid of the red outline, you might as well need to update the `boxStrokeColor` programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use doOnTextChanged listner on edit text and check whenever user write something is there error enable if then make it null and change box color

```
   binding.loginEmailValue.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
        if(binding.loginEmailContainer.error.toString().isNotEmpty()){
            binding.loginEmailContainer.error = null
        }
    }
```